# Select a text string

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I have this python code that shows me links. How do I select one of these links? You can select one of these links, so that it contains the text "NICZ1524002"

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r= requests.get("https://moredrops.cl/Drops/Brands/c/dropsMarcas")
data=r.text
soup= BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
tags= soup.find_all('a' , class_='name')

for tag in tags:
    print(tag.get('href'))
```

Comment: you can search keyword of "BeautifulSoup soup.select()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using urlparse to get the url leaf:

```
import os
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r= requests.get("https://moredrops.cl/Drops/Brands/c/dropsMarcas")
data=r.text
soup= BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
tags= soup.find_all('a' , class_='name')

for tag in tags:
    url = tag.get('href')
    a = urlparse(url)
    if os.path.basename(a.path) == "NICZ1524002":
      print(url)
```